# How can I create a database in SQL Server by code first entity framework 6?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2012. I want to use Entity Framework 6 code-first. When I create model and db-context file and when I run my project it does not create any database in my SQK Server. I want to know what is wrong?

I want to know how can I create database by code first in my SQL Server not in SQL Server Express or Compact. How can I create it? I try scaffolding too but it dos not work true and does not create any database. Any tips or trick would be welcome

This is my `web.config` setting :

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="dbRaja" 
        connectionString="Data Source=hp-PC;Initial Catalog=Raja;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and its my datacontext :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Raja1.Models
{
    public class dbRaja : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
        // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
        // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
        // 
        // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Raja1.Models.Raja1Context>());

        public DbSet<Raja1.Models.Spareparts> Spareparts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens and what does not? Code looks basically OK.

Comment: i dont know why it dosent create my database when it run ???

Comment: How do you determine it doesn't? Errors when querying/inserting?

Comment: i test another project and using ef version 5 then it work by scaffolding but when i use ef version 6  it show me an error i dont know why

Comment: And are you sure it's EF6? NuGet only shows me EF5.

Comment: yes becuse  i install by this statement  PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre

Comment: just i run it when i run my project it have to create my database

Comment: No, it creates your Db when you do the first query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33016/discussion-between-sara-sodagari-and-henk-holterman)

Comment: Run a query. You should either get a Db or an exception.

Comment: see i test anotehr project by sacffolding in ef 6 but it show me this error
unable to retrive metadata for raja.models.person unable to cast object of type system.data.entity.core.objectscontext to type system.data.objects.objectcontext
when i want use scaffolding in ef 6 for creating my controller and views and dbcontext file

Comment: Alway include exception and error messages in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your `DbContext` to use the intended connection string. It will default to one named the same as your application (i.e. "Raja1"), whereas your connection string is named "dbRaja".

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext : base("name=dbRaja")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in your app start:

```
using (var context = new YOUR_DB_CONTEXT()) {
    if (!context.Database.Exists()) {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```